# Does the pushout of monomorphisms in Abelian category include into the direct sum?

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be an Abelian category. Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be objects in $\mathbf{A}$, with $\iota_{1}: X \hookrightarrow Z$ and $\iota_{2}: X \hookrightarrow Y$ monomorphisms.
Is it true, and if yes why, that the pushout $P$ of $\iota_{1}$ and $\iota_{2}$ includes into the direct sum $Z \oplus Y$? 
Because I have been told that this is true since $\iota_{1}$ and $\iota_{2}$ are monomorphisms, but I fail to see it.

By Abelian category I mean a category such that (i) it has the zero object; (ii) it has all binary biproducts; (iii) every morphism has kernel and cokernel; (iv) every monomorphism is a kernel, and every epimorphism is a cokernel.

Edit: I realised that it is not true in general. I would still like to know which other hypotheses I have to add to obtain the result.

Comment: By construction, the pushout $Z\sqcup_X Y$ should be a quotient of $Z\oplus Y$ rather than a subobject...

Comment: I know, but I am looking for the conditions under which it is actually a subobject.